Filling value in a pandas dataframe based on grouping
This is the result I get:

This is the result I want to get:

This is the code I use, how can I modify it?
group = ['ENTITY']

def shift_if_different(group):
    group['PREV_LOT'] = group['LOT'].shift()
    group['PREV_LOT'] = group.apply(lambda row: row['PREV_LOT'] if row['PREV_LOT'] != row['LOT'] else np.nan, axis=1)
    return group

df = df.groupby(group).apply(shift_if_different)


Post your inputs and expected output as text...

You are not showing us any input. Please provide it as text, not an image, along with the desired output based on the input sample. Use df.to_dict() and post in a code block with triple backticks (```).

You can use this approach:
df = pd.DataFrame({"LOT": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D"]})

df.loc[df["LOT"] != df["LOT"].shift(), "PREV_LOT"] = df["LOT"].shift()
df["PREV_LOT"] = df["PREV_LOT"].ffill()

  LOT PREV_LOT
0   A     None
1   A     None
2   B        A
3   B        A
4   C        B
5   D        C
6   D        C
7   D        C


or with a one liner df['PREV_LOT'] = df['LOT'].shift().where(lambda x: x.ne(df['LOT'])).ffill() but indeed, seems the logical approach with the need!
